# Отправка теста.

Tags: css, javascript, html, php, mysql

Я создаю Html страничку, которая позволяет пользователю создавать тесты произвольной длинны(т.е. пользователь сам решает сколько вопросов будет в тесте). Как добавлять поля для ввода новых вопросов в тесте по нажатию на кнопку с помощью javaScript я разобрался. Но я не знаю, как лучше отправлять эти вопросы на сервер для обработки? Т.е. я же заранее не знаю сколько будет вопросов и соответственно не знаю сколько переменных создать.

Answer (score 1):

Одна из штук, которые мне нравятся в PHP - автоматическое преобразование присланных формами данных в массивы. Самый простой способ организовать непересекающиеся данные (без PHP) был бы таким:

```
Введите вопрос:
<input name="question1_name" type="text" />
Варианты ответа:
<input name="question1_answer1" type="text" />
<input name="question1_answer2" type="text" />
...
```

Это позволяет избежать коллизий, но разбиение данных по вопросам превращается в ад. PHP же позволяет задать данные в форме вот так:

```
Введите вопрос:
<input name="questions[1][name]" type="text" />
Варианты ответа:
<input name="questions[1][answers][]" type="text" />
<input name="questions[1][answers][]" type="text" />
...
```

При этом в глобальный массив $_POST данные попадут в следующем виде:

```
questions => array:
    1 => array:
         name => %введенное имя%,
         answers => array:
             0 => %первый вариант%,
             1 => %второй вариант%,
             ...
```

т.е. уже автоматом будут разбиты на массивы. В этом случае придется отслеживать количество вопросов на странице, чтобы избежать коллизии, но для ответов достаточно просто указывать [], чтобы сформировать массив.
Несмотря на то, что длина пришедшего списка вопросов заранее не определена, работа с ним не представляет особой сложности:

```
foreach ($_POST['questions'] as $question) {
    $name = $question['name']; // название
    $answers = $question['answers']; // массив ответов
    $test->addQuestion($name, $answers);
}
```

Извините за сумбурный ответ, надеюсь, из примера понятна организация.